# Combining predicted results of Sci-Kit learn classifier with original test set data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a ML project (a binary classification problem) and was able to run successfully few Sci-Kit classifiers (RF, MLP, Extra Trees).

My question is now I have "Predict_Probas" results which I have converted into a Pandas Data frame and I would like to combine this with my original test data which later I will export in CSV. This I need to show to my management as the final result of my ML project. The issue is I adopted following approach -

- First standardized the whole data (using StandardScaler)
- Then encoded the data using One-Hot encoding.
- Then using Train_test_split, split the standardized and encoded data into two parts

How can I now get my original test data back with (without standardization & one-hot encoding) with names of columns intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's done bit differently - we split data set in the *original format*, before doing preprocessing operations.

The preprocessing operations will be executed against the training data set (`X_train`) and passed to the estimator.

Then the same set of preprocessing operations will be executed also against the test data set (`X_test`) in order to estimate (score) your model using the unseen subset of data.

In practice often it's done using [Pipeline()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) class:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
        train_test_split(df['text'], df['label'], test_size=0.25)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler',StandardScaler()),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

predicted = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thanks Max, I will try this approach and let you know in case of any issues. However meanwhile, can you please tell me how do you run "cross_val_score" and "cross_val_predict" on X_train, y_train when model (such as Logistic Regression) is given under Pipeline? Will it be possible to run cross_val_score as cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, cv=5, random_state=1)?

Comment: @AbhikJha, usually i'm using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#examples-using-sklearn-model-selection-gridsearchcv) which is doing that for me automatically...